# Regex to mask the password with star * in a given string statement in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a SQL select query in formatted as a string, and it contains the user/password condition in where clause. I need to log the complete query by masking the password value with `*`. So need a correct regEx to mask the user/password value with `*` .

## sample SQL:

### pattern 1:

SELECT e.id, e.userid, e.firstname, e.lastname, e.middlename, e.nickname from emp e where e.state = 1 AND lower(e.userid) = ''"

### pattern 2:

SELECT e.id, e.email, e.userid from order e where e.state = 1 AND e.userid = ''"

I have used the following but it doesnt satisfy both the scenario mentioned

```
sql.replaceAll("e.userid.*\\s*=\\s*[\\p{ASCII}&&[^\\s]]*", "(e.userid) = ****")

sql.replaceAll("e.userid.*\\s*=\\s*[\\p{ASCII}&&[^\\s]]*", "(e.userid) = ****")
```

**Note:** the userid value doesnt contain space. and it can have alphanumeric.

basically I need help to match the below 2 pattern

1. I expect the output of **lower(e.userid) = 'user1'** to be **lower(e.userid) = '****'** while logging.
2. I expect the output of **e.userid = 'user1' AND**  to be **e.userid = '****' AND**  while logging.

Comment: Better wrap it all into a function accepting name, password etc. . Then in there create the query and log everything but the password. You'll just end up leaking passwords with your approach.

Comment: plaintext passwords shouldn't be stored in database

Comment: Are you using parameterized queries? If not -- you should. Not only will it help with problems like this (since the parameter values are not actually part of the SQL query string), but it'll also save you from SQL injection. As a rough rule of thumb, if you're using string concatenation to create a SQL string, you're probably in trouble (that's not always true, but it's a good starting point).

Comment: Apart form the obvious flaws, try this: https://regex101.com/r/KJZaBc/1

Comment: @I3ck yes i agree with you. but currently i cannot change the signatures as it is being consumed by various external places whcih i dont have control.

Comment: @nandsito yes you are right, basically i wanted to mask the userid also in the logs in my use case, so i mentioned user/pwd, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @yshavit yes valid point.

Comment: @oneinbillion you said it's consumed elsewhere. But are you creating the query? If so, my suggestion should still be possible? Also make sure to implement hashing and prevent injections etc. as others suggested